# viewDidLoad() not running after segue

Tags: ios, swift

I'm performing a segue from one table view to another.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "types", sender: productList[indexPath.row])
}
```

It should run the `viewDidLoad()` of the new TableView described by the custom class of the ViewController (Which I've declared in Storyboard)

```
func viewDidLoad(parent: String) {
    print("This should print")
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //self.typeTableView.delegate = self
    //self.typeTableView.dataSource = self

    //Set reference
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    //Retrieve posts
    handle = ref?.child(parent).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let product = snapshot.key as? String
        if let actualProduct = product
        {
            self.productList.append(actualProduct)
            self.typeTableView.reloadData()
        }

    })


}
```

Any Idea why this might be happening?

Comment: What is the "parent" parameter?, UIVIewController's viewDidLoad() function is has no parameters

Comment: parent parameter is the segues sender `sender: productList[indexPath.row]`

Comment: I think it did not work because actually you are creating a function named viewDidLoad with a parameter for yourself and have not called it anywhere. Let override the viewDidLoad() function of the UIViewController, as @sulthan has pointed out. If you need to pass data between two ViewController, learn how to pass data via "prepareForSegue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed navigation controller to your destination controller
 and make a segue from current table views cell to it with identifier ***types***. 
Then add below method after your 
     *func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}*

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "types" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = productList[indexPath.row] as! yourProductType
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! YourDestinationViewController
            controller.yourProductProperty = object
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to declare yourProductProperty in your Destination controller so that you can access current product object in it.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` has no parameters and needs an `override` clause:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I add override I get an error **Method does not override any method from its superclass**

Comment: @ThomasKearsley That means you are not putting the method into a `UIViewController`.

Comment: I'm only able to override when I remove the parameter.

Comment: You cannot add any custom parameters in overrides.

Comment: How can I transfer this `indexPath.row` value? Do I need to create a new object of type ViewController after the segue?

Comment: @ThomasKearsley You create a `var product: ...` on the controller, access the `destinationViewController` in `prepare(for:sender:)` and set it there.

Comment: `var selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "types", sender: selectedIndex)` Like this?

Comment: Check the other answer, it gives a nice example.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature is

```
func viewDidLoad(parent: String) {
```

but it should be

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Your code
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

are you using same class to tableviewcell ? if yes then keep different identifier **[RESUE IDENTIFIER]** for both tableview.